# Google login error - User cancelled login or did not fully authorize

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Used the "angularx-social-login" npm module for login, it's working fine on browser when run ionic serve cmd but not working in device.

Show error :

```
ERROR: Uncaught (in promise): User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.
```

```
this.OAuth.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(res => { 
 console.log(res);
   }):
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an open issue on angularx-social-login as per the links below:

> https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/6
>
> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-integrate-facebook-google-login-in-ionic-pwa/98772

If you are using Ionic to achieve logging in using Google, Ionic already has native plugin to do that

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, I am trying to create one social login module and try to support both angular and ionic therefore I am using angularx-social-login module only.

Comment: Maybe you could try this one and see if it works, haven't really tested though but some people says it is working.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-social-login